# moving to softlayer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dedicated-server, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Am planning to migrate one of my rails application from Heroku to Softlayer.
I got a softlayer account as well. But I have absolutely no idea about dedicated servers how they work what are the prerequisites.
Some of the key points I think needs to be taken care for migration and server deployment are

1. Setup
2. Data Migration
3. Deployment
4. Performance

I would like to know the best way to setup a server on Softlayer and migrate my application data from Heroku to SoftLayer

Answer (score 3):

Running a dedicated Rails server (any dedicated server for that matter) is a lot of work.  You have to concern yourself with:

1. Linux distro and updates
2. MySQL/PostgreSQL/MongoDB database installation and updates
3. Configuring backup solution
4. App server install and configuration
5. Web server configuration
6. Write your own Capistrano scripts to deploy

I have a dedicated server on Softlayer now (Windows server) and I can say they are awesome.  They go beyond the call of duty to help you.  But when it comes to Rails servers I'd rather not spend my time with all the configuration issues.

For a step up from Heroku I'd recommend [Engine Yard](http://www.engineyard.com) instead.  They give you more control of your instance while managing on the server-side maintenance that I really don't want to worry about.  I have an instance there that runs great.

Comment: thanks for the insights, dedicated servers might be painful sometimes. PaaS rocks anyway :)